# Das bisher erreichte – groß oder klein?

Tags: capitalization, past-participle

*Das Erreichte* klingt ja erstmal nach Substantiv, aber es muss auch ein Etwas geben, das erreicht worden ist, also wäre „erreicht worden zu sein“ ein Attribut von diesem Etwas. Mein Herz sagt ja „klein“, aber was ist laut aktueller amtlicher Rechtschreibung korrekt?

Comment: Das Erreichte ist etwas Großgeschriebenes.

Comment: Wenn es unbedingt und zweifelsfrei klein sein soll, dann umformulieren: _[das,] was bisher erreicht [wurde / [worden] ist], …_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kommt darauf, ob es noch ein zugehöriges Substantiv gibt oder nicht (welches direkt folgen kann, aber je nach Satzkonstruktion nicht muss, wie beispielsweise in Chirlus Kommentar).

> Das bisher Erreichte ist nicht genug

Hier wird substantiviert, daher groß (substantiviertes 2. Partizip, um genau zu sein).

> Das bisher erreichte Ziel war nur der erste Schritt

Hier ist es klar...

Comment: Das zugehörige Substantiv muß aber nicht unbedingt tatsächlich folgen, es kann auch mitgedacht sein: _Viele Ziele stehen noch aus, das bisher erreichte war nur der erste Schritt._

Comment: Da hast du Recht.

Comment: @chirlu Dein Kommentar sollte meiner Meinung nach auch in der Antwort enthalten sein.

Comment: @chirlu: Also geht's doch auch klein? Mein Satz ist: "Als Mensch würden Sie [...] sich mit dem bisher erreichten zufriedengeben." Ist hier ein Substantiv mitgedacht? Mein Gefühl sagt, wie gesagt, dass das klein sein sollte...

Comment: Du musst schon versuchen zu verstehen, wie die Regel funktioniert. Man kann natürlich "das erreichte" auch klein schreiben, aber nicht, wenn es (wie in deinem Fall) wie ein Substantiv gebraucht wird. Meine beiden und Chirlus Beispiele machen das klar. Zitiere mal deinen kompletten Satz. Dann können wir dir sagen ob groß oder klein. Ich vermute, dein Gefühl ist falsch. Die Frage ist doch ganz einfach: verwendest du es in deinem Satz als Adjektiv (dann klein) oder substantiviert (dann groß)?

Comment: @chirlu in deinem Beispiel kommt es übrigens darauf an. Bezieht man "erreichte" auf "erreichte Ziele", dann hast du Recht. Wenn du aber sagen willst dass noch einige Ziele ausstehen und **alles was man bisher erreicht hat** noch nicht genügt, dann müsste man es groß schreiben. Ein schönes Beispiel also dafür, dass man aus der Schreibung auch den Bezug herstellen kann.

Comment: @lukascoenig in deinem Satz, so wie oben zitiert, muss es groß geschrieben werden.

Comment: Ach so, diese Lesart von @chirlu's Satz ist an mir vorbeigegangen. Na gut, dann schreib ich's halt schweren Herzens groß... Aber wenn ich Duden wär, würde ich mir eine Regel einfallen lassen, sodass es klein geschrieben werden muss. Gefällt mir irgendwie besser.

Answer (score 6):

Laut [Regel 72](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#K72) werden als Substantive gebrauchte Adjektive und Partizipien in der Regel großgeschrieben.

Hier ein Ausschnitt mit Beispielen:

> **Regel 72:**
>
> 1. Als Substantive gebrauchte Adjektive und Partizipien werden in der Regel großgeschrieben.
>
>    *das Gute, die Angesprochene, Altes und Neues; und Ähnliches (Abk. u. Ä.), wir haben Folgendes/das Folgende geplant; der zuletzt Genannte
>      (oder Zuletztgenannte), die zu spät Gekommenen (oder
>      Zuspätgekommenen); die Rat Suchenden (oder Ratsuchenden); das der
>      Schülerin Bekannte, das zu Beachtende, das dort zu Findende; etwas auf
>      Englisch sagen; im Allgemeinen; der Einzelne; in Blau und Gelb; die
>      Russisch-Orthodoxen*
> 2. Häufig zeigen vorangehende Wörter wie „alles", „etwas", „nichts", „viel", „wenig" den substantivischen Gebrauch an.
>
>    *alles Gewollte, etwas [besonders] Gutes, nichts Wichtiges, viel Unnötiges, wenig Durchdachtes*

Answer (score 0):

I would say as it's being used as a noun, it's a capital.

Comment: Warum auf Englisch antworten, wenn die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt ist?

Comment: Entschuldigung. Es soll grossgeschrieben werden weil es als Substantiv benutzt is.